# Динамический запрос из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Помогите обдумать такую вещь:
на сайте есть поиск с фильтрами и нужно составить динамический запрос к бд.
Один из фильтров может быть такого плана: стандартно стоит некий диапозон значений от 1 до 10, из от 1 до 10 возможных т.е. весь диапозон.

Пользователь же может этот диапозон сузить, допустим: поставить от 2 до 5, а может и не менять его..

Так вот, как бы так правильнее составить запрос?
Как вариант мог бы тупо поставить условие, и проверять.. если диапозон менялся - условие было бы вида

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE diapozon BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

если же не менялся то

```
SELECT row FROM table
```

Но фильтров у меня много.. условие в php перед составлением запроса не вариант, можно ли както в самом mysql условия делать?

и еще вопрос, в случае если диапозон не менялся, как будет лучше:

```
    SELECT row FROM table WHERE diapozon BETWEEN 1 AND 10
или
    SELECT row FROM table
```

т.е. вообще без условия вытаскивать (вообще всё), или всетаки ставить условие, но говорить чтобы тянул всё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше 
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE diapozon > {min_value} AND diapozon < {max_value}

Comment: это лучше чем BETWEEN, и быстрее

Comment: Спасибо, учтем. А что на счет условия? Прийдется в php проверять изменял ли пользователь диапозон в фильтре и в случае если да - посылать другой запрос, а первый игнорировать?

Answer (score 1):

Быстрей будет `select row from table`.

Comment: Ну я догадывался, поэтому и хочу понять, можно ли делать условия, чтобы в случае, если он юзер, менял диапазон - учитывать диапазон, а если нет - то нет.

Comment: да имеет смысл